# VB.Net ListBox datasource deletion

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the Id column (it's the primary key) from a `ListBox` that has a `DataSet` to fill it selected index so I can delete it?

Usually I'd do `lstBox.SelectedIndex` but i'm guessing that's just the array index rather than the primary key. So how do I get the row for that index?

Answer (score 0):

A [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will actually use the [DefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as its data source. If you don't specify a [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return the current selected [DataRowView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use this to obtain the primary key.

```
Dim drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(Me.ListBox1.SelectedValue, DataRowView)
Dim pk As Integer = drv.Row.Item("id")
```

However, if you specify the value member to be the name of your primary key column, the selected value will return the primary key of the current selected item.

```
Me.ListBox1.ValueMember = "id"
```

```
Dim pk As Integer = DirectCast(Me.ListBox1.SelectedValue, Integer)
```